# how to write a runbook for change UDR's nexthop if specific vm's IP is timeout in Azure

Tags: azure, scripting, powershell-3.0, azure-runbook

i want to have a runbook for change UDR's nexthop if specific Vm's IP is timeout, how to do ? i'm a network administrator so i don't understand C++ or powershell

Answer (score 0):

I see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d835001-fa0f-49c9-b8be-551fea513e97/how-to-write-a-runbook-for-change-udrs-nexthop-if-specific-vms-ip-is-timeout-in-azure?forum=azureautomation) thread as similar one which looks like is answered!!

I hope this update benefits broader audience as well. Cheers!!